# Create telegram channel in nodejs or angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to have a link,a button, or similar on a website that permits to create a new channel?

E.g., when I click on the link, I send a message with my credentials (phone number is enough i tihink, but not sure) that says "create a new channel called foo".

Is that possible (and if, how can I do that)?

I searched in the [telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/) but I had no clue..
I also found [this](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/dot-build/telegram-js/) but I have no idea how to do what I want.

Comment: As far as I am aware, bots are not able to create channels, groups or start a conversation with a user.

Comment: thanks for your hint, I changed my request from creation from a bot to creation from an account: I think you're right about bots! What about telegram accounts?

Comment: Well, I have never tried to use accounts, but I assume that that should definitely be possible in some way, I myself just don't know it